# Python Vectorization Split String

Tags: python, string, split, vectorization

I want to use vectorization to create a column in a pandas data frame that retrieve the second/last part of a string, from each row in a column, that is split on '_'. I tried this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Var1'] = ["test1_test2","test3_test4"]
df['Var2'] = [[df['Var1'].str.split('_')][0]][0]
df

           Var1  Var2
0   test1_test2 test3
1   test3_test4 test4
```

Which is obviously incorrect as I should get test2 and test 4 in row 0 and 1 of column Var2 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.str.split('_')` method along with `.str[-1]` to retrieve the second/last part of each string in the column.

Following is the updated code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Var1'] = ["test1_test2", "test3_test4"]
df['Var2'] = df['Var1'].str.split('_').str[-1]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
          Var1   Var2
0  test1_test2  test2
1  test3_test4  test4
```

In the above code, `df['Var1'].str.split('_')` splits each string in the 'Var1' column by the '_' delimiter, and `.str[-1]` selects the last part of the split string for each row.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Var2'] = df['Var1'].str.extract("_([^_]+)$")
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
          Var1   Var2
0  test1_test2  test2
1  test3_test4  test4
```

The regular expression `"_([^_]+)$"` matches the last split.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df["Var2"] = df['Var1'].apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[-1])
```

`df` output:

```
          Var1   Var2
0  test1_test2  test2
1  test3_test4  test4
```